# How to set GCP Alert threshold based on time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dynamic, threshold, google-cloud-monitoring, log-based-metrics

I have a Google Dataflow Pipeline that logs JSON similar to the following.

```
jsonPayload: {
    metric: "viewings-per-second",
    time: "2023-03-28 17:16:14",
    value: 15
}
```

I created a Log-based-metric to extract the value and used it in a Cloud Monitoring Alert with a fixed threshold. My actual requirement though, is to have two thresholds - one during peak hours (6AM - 1AM) and one during off-peak (1AM - 6AM).

How can I create a dynamic threshold, if possible? Perhaps I can use Monitoring Query Language (MQL) or something.

One alternate method I could think of was to create two Log-based-metrics and put the hour condition via Log Query Language (LQL). While testing my query in Log Explorer, this works:

```
jsonPayload.time>="2023-03-28 06:00:00"
```

However, I am unable to figure out how to extract the time alone from the datetime value.

As a last resort, I guess I can make the Dataflow Pipeline log just the hour or time, but was wondering whether there is a better solution.

**EDIT:**

My current LQL

```
logName="projects/example-project/logs/dataflow-viewings-per-second"
jsonPayload.metric="viewings-per-second"
jsonPayload.time>="2023-03-28 06:00:00"
```

Comment: From where you cannot extract the time alone from datetime?  is it from LQL?

Comment: @DharaniDharGolladasari Yes, I tried extracting time using LQL. I edited the question to include my current LQL

Comment: Unfortunately the GCP follows ISO-8601 time format for logs and LQL, So try following this format like **YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssz** . Refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language#search_by_time) for more information.

Comment: @DharaniDharGolladasari ok, but how do I extract the time value in LQL, if I have the right format? There is a timestamp property with the time in that format and I can use that as well.

Comment: Also, I have already gone through that documentation. Even without the 'T' format, the conditions work, but I have to mention date as well. I just need to extract the hour from the timestamp